# Custom Python library throws ImportError only in ArchLinux

Tags: python, ubuntu, makefile, python-2.7, archlinux

I have a question.

I have a Makefile, which compiles some C code with Python.h into a `.so` file. I added `@install -m` statement to put the `.so` file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, and when I imported this library from inside my Python scripts, it worked in Ubuntu 11.10 just fine.

Eventually I had to run all of this in Arch Linux, and I noticed that there was only one file named dist-packages and no directory, and also, there is nothing inside `/usr/local/lib` and python2.7 is in `/usr/lib` instead. So I changed the install path to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead. Now it throws this error:

`ImportError: <objectname>.so: Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When I make using the Makefile, the `.so` file also gets created in the local directory, which should already work without putting that `.so` file in that specified path. The path where I am putting that `.so` file is in sys.path in Python2.7. I am clueless how to resolve this issue.

I am adding the complete Makefile here for better understanding:

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7

PYINC = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
PYLIB = python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
NUMPYINC = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/

BASIC_NAME = vision
LIB_NAME = lib$(BASIC_NAME).so
MODULE_NAME = $(BASIC_NAME).so

all:: $(MODULE_NAME) 

#link compiled python wrapper code with c code and generate python module
$(MODULE_NAME): $(LIB_NAME) vision.o 
        gcc -shared -Wall vision.o -o $(MODULE_NAME) -l$(PYLIB) -L. -l$(BASIC_NAME)    

#generate c library, consisting of compiled c files (object files)
$(LIB_NAME): fireflymv.o image.o
        gcc -shared -Wall fireflymv.o image.o -o $(LIB_NAME) -ldc1394

#compile single c code file (basic c code)
fireflymv.o: fireflymv.c fireflymv.h
        gcc -Wall -fPIC -o fireflymv.o -c fireflymv.c 

#compile single c code file (basic c code)
image.o: image.c image.h
        gcc -Wall -fPIC -o image.o -c image.c

#compile single c code file (python wrapper code)
vision.o: vision.c
        gcc -Wall -fPIC -I$(PYINC) -I$(NUMPYINC) -o vision.o -c vision.c 

#install basic c code library into linux system (root permissions required)
install:
        @echo Installing $(LIB_NAME) and $(MODULE_NAME) to /usr/local/lib
        @install -m 0777 $(LIB_NAME) /usr/local/lib
        @install -m 0777 $(MODULE_NAME) /usr/local/lib
        @ldconfig

#remove basic c code library from linux system (root permissions required)
uninstall:
        @echo Removing $(LIB_NAME) and $(MODULE_NAME) from /usr/local/lib
        @-$(RM) /usr/local/lib/$(LIB_NAME)
        @-$(RM) /usr/local/lib/$(MODULE_NAME)
        @ldconfig

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.pyc
```

This creates two files, vision.so and libvision.so. Vision.so is the one that should be imported in the Python scripts. Libvision.so is the one it says it can't find. If I do `ldd libvision.so`, all connections are fine. If I do `ldd vision.so`, I get `libvision.so ===> not found` although it is right there in the same directory. I also checked the file size. It seems about right and it is not a 0 kb file.

Comment: How are you importing the file?

Comment: Once the `.so` object is in a place that is in Python's sys.path, I just use an import statement inside the Python script.

Comment: Is your shebang line `python2` or `python`|`python3`? If it's `python` you'll get py3k being called, and the module wouldn't be available.

Comment: In the Makefile, it is specified as Python2.7. Also, when I am running the script, I am doing this: `python2.7 <scriptname.py>`, so I see no reason for Python 3 being called. I do not even have Python 3 installed in my system. If I only write `python` in the terminal, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dist-packages` is a Debian/Ubuntu invention, created to avoid conflicts between distribution packages installed from `.deb` files and Python packages installed using `sudo python setup.py install`.  Upstream Python only knows about `site-packages`.

Now about the import error -- it sounds like your `.so` is linked to other libraries that are not present on the ArchLinux system in question.  Can you run `ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yourlibrary.so` and see if all the external references point to existing library files?

Comment: [Here](http://tinypaste.com/01fb1dd9) is the Makefile. I am sorry I did not post this earlier. As you can see, this creates too `.so` files: vision.so and libvision.so. When I do ldd on libvision.so, everything checks out. When I do ldd on vision.so, which is the one I actually import in my Python scripts, it says libvision.so is not found. The <objectname>.so in the original post is also libvision.so. So, vision.so needs libvision.so to work, but it does not find it. I do not understand why!

Comment: I did not use `dist-packages` and `site-packages` at all and this time I have used `usr/local/lib` and added a `.pth` file in `site-packages` with the path `/usr/local/lib`. Same error again. Sorry if I forgot to change the `make uninstall` part. I never use it anyway.

Comment: It sounds like you need to move libvision.so into /usr/lib, or move it to /usr/local/lib and make sure /etc/ld.so.conf mentions /usr/local/lib (and then run `ldconfig`), or add the containing directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH before you start your Python process.

Comment: Moving it to `/usr/lib` and adding the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `ldconfig` afterwards worked like a charm! Thank you very much! I cannot mark a comment as the right answer, so I am marking the original answer as the correct one.